# Does sort (Unix) work on hexadecimal input?

Tags: sorting

I have a file where each line is a number printed in hexadecimal, for example a0

Can I sort it with sort -n or does it have to be in base 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  I did some research and testing.  Unfortunately sort -n does not give the correct results when sorting strings.

I tried the following data set:

```
000 aa
00a0 dd
00b0 ee
0d0b ff
cc gg
0100 cc
```

And the output was almost, but not quite correct:

```
000 aa
00a0 dd
00b0 ee
0d0b ff
cc gg
0100 cc
1000 bb
```

Note the "cc" line - which should be above the 0d0b line.